# value of TextFormField remain same after change the object

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

here the video to problem

https://drive.google.com/file/d/15WRTARBEcg9NdTW9NO-SyVG0hyZtuu1e/view?usp=sharing

I have dynamic form inside MyForm.dart contain list of pages and each page contain list of widgets to render the page from that list, then I change the index of page at runtime with provider

the problem is when I render first page and type value inside the textformfiled then increment size of page to render the second page. the second page render with same value

#### MyForm class

```
/// responsible for hold the data needed for form ex: list of page,
/// mange display pages, create the data object that will carry the whole Form
class MyForm extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyFormState createState() => _MyFormState();
}

class _MyFormState extends State<MyForm> {
  FormProvider _formProvider;

  /// TODO
  final List<Widget> pageElements1 = [
    TextFiledBuilder(TextFiledModel(mLabel: 'اسم الملك', required: true)),
    TextFiledBuilder(TextFiledModel(mLabel: 'رقم الهوية', required: true)),
  ];

  final List<Widget> pageElements2 = [
    TextFiledBuilder(TextFiledModel(mLabel: 'القسم', required: true)),
    TextFiledBuilder(TextFiledModel(mLabel: 'حالة المنشاة', required: true)),
  ];
  int pageIndex;

  List<PageForm> pages;
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    pages = [
      PageForm(elements: pageElements1),
      PageForm(elements: pageElements2),
      // spacial type
    ];
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    _formProvider = Provider.of<FormProvider>(context);
    Provider.of<FormProvider>(context, listen: false)
        .setPageLength(pages.length);
    pageIndex = _formProvider.getPageIndex;
    print('## $runtimeType @@ build() ');
    return pages[pageIndex];
  }
}
```

#### PageForm class

```
class PageForm extends StatefulWidget {
  /// list of element like [CustomWidgetBuilder] and special type of element
  /// like [DisplayImages] and [MapLocation]
  final List<Widget> elements;
  // fixme add page title
  PageForm({this.elements});

  @override
  _PageFormState createState() => _PageFormState();
}

class _PageFormState extends State<PageForm> {
  // key used to validate the entire page
  final GlobalKey<FormState> _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
  FormProvider _formProvider;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    _formProvider = Provider.of<FormProvider>(context);

    print('@@ $runtimeType @@ build()');
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: SharedAppBar(
        mTitle: 'page title',
      ),
      floatingActionButtonLocation: FloatingActionButtonLocation.centerDocked,
      floatingActionButton: CustomFABs(
        leftButton: RoundedIconButton(
          mIcon: Icons.arrow_back,
          mOnPress: () {
            // next button
            int index = _formProvider.getPageIndex;
            _formProvider.setPageIndex(index + 1);
          },
        ),
        rightButton: RoundedIconButton(
          mIcon: Icons.arrow_forward,
          mOnPress: () {    
            int newIndex = _formProvider.getPageIndex;
            _formProvider.setPageIndex(newIndex - 1);
          },
        ),
      ),
      body: Form(
        key: _formKey,
        child: Column(
          children: [
            Column(
              children: widget.elements,
            ),
            ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: () {
              },
              child: Text('استرجاع'),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

#### TextFiledBuilder class

```
class TextFiledBuilder extends StatefulWidget /* with HaveFormKey*/ {
  final TextFiledModel model;

  TextFiledBuilder(this.model);

  @override
  _TextFiledBuilderState createState() => _TextFiledBuilderState();
}

class _TextFiledBuilderState extends State<TextFiledBuilder> {
  
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return TextFormField(
      textAlign: TextAlign.center,
      decoration: kTextFieldDecoration.copyWith(
        labelText: widget.model.mLabel,
      ),
      validator: (value) {
        if (widget.model.required && value.isEmpty) {
          return Strings.requiredFiled;
        }
        return null;
      },
    );
  }
}
```

#### FormProvider

```
class FormProvider extends ChangeNotifier {
  int _pageIndex = 0;

  int get getPageIndex => _pageIndex;
  int _pagesLength;

  void reset() => _pageIndex = 0;

  /// set the size of pages, this method it's just helper to handle counter of
  /// ++ and -- the index of page in order to display it so we don't need
  /// [notifyListeners] to change UI
  void setPageLength(int length) {
    _pagesLength = length;
    print('@@ $runtimeType @@ pageLen= $_pagesLength');

    //notifyListeners();
  }

  /// update index of pages in the [MyForm] to display correct ui
  void setPageIndex(int index) {
    print('@@ $runtimeType @@ setPageIndex() index= $index'
        ' pagesLen = $_pagesLength '
        ' pageIndex = $_pageIndex');
    if (index > -1 && index < _pagesLength) {
      _pageIndex = index;
      notifyListeners();
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that your TextFiledBuilder needs a key to differentiate from the previous widget.
Change your TextFiledBuilder to this.

```
    class TextFiledBuilder extends StatefulWidget /* with HaveFormKey*/ {
     final TextFiledModel model;
     Key key;

     TextFiledBuilder(this.model, this.key);

     @override
     _TextFiledBuilderState createState() => _TextFiledBuilderState();
     }
```

And while calling it, call it like this

```
     TextFiledBuilder(TextFiledModel(mLabel: 'القسم', required: true), 
      UniqueKey()),
```

Comment: yeah it's working thanks in advance, but i need to understand how two of them took same key although they four different objects?

Comment: They are not same keys, UniqueKey() generates a new key every time. Your can read more about UniqueKey().

Comment: Also, if the answer helped can you upvote it as well, please ?

Comment: I mean in first case before UniqueKey()

Comment: I vote it up aleardy and website tell me that "Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score."

Comment: Okay, i got your question now, actually they didn't have keys earlier, & thats the way flutter works. For that to understand you need to read about "how flutter renders widget" & "why keys are important". I wont be able to explain them, but you can always google.